# ejabberd registration timeout

Tags: configuration, timeout, ejabberd

When member is registered and captcha is turned on, member see such windows (sorry, it's in russian)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVvly.png)

And there is timeout, after passing that time member get mistake. Time is very short, the user does not have time to enter captcha and register.
What is the option in config, to fix this? How can I add time to this registration timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not related to the CAPTCHA itself. In fact, this happens with connections to clients, servers and services (like transports): ejabberd  waits 30 seconds in a connection that is being negotiatied. If the connection is not correctly negotiatied in that timeout, it closes the connection.

There is only one option to change that, so this affects all the connections, not only clients, also servers and services. Simply add in ejabberd.yml something like this:

```
negotiation_timeout: 55
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's not documented in docs.ejabberd.im, so if not you, I would never solve this problem.
One more question. If this option turned off, default value for c2s is 30. And what is default s2s timeout? I mean, if I put "negotiation_timeout: 55", won't I decrease s2s timeouts if it was more by default?

Comment: negotiation_timeout is a global option, so its value affects all the possible usages. By default it's 30 seconds, and that applies to c2s, s2s, and services.